# How to customize dx-data-grid export to excel with more columns than the grid columns?

Tags: angular, devextreme-angular, dx-data-grid

In our angular application, we have used DxDataGridModule from "devextreme-angular" for listing.

The default export to excel functionality is working fine.

How can I add more columns to the excel?

How to create one or more worksheets in excel and populate data?

Please help to achieve the same